In CoreWCF, how can I replace references to http://tempuri.org/ with my own namespace?
I am trying to make a CoreWCF SOAP endpoint which is backwards compatible with a legacy .NET Framework SOAP API.    One problem remaining is that if I call any method (OperationContract), the XML output references http://tempuri.org/ instead of my custom namespace.  I can't seem to see any way to change this value. Here's a snippet of my code:
[ServiceContract(Name = "UploaderAPI")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://x-rm.com")]
public interface IUploaderAPISoap
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://x-rm.com/uploaderapi/HelloWorld")]
    HelloWorldResponse HelloWorld(string echo);
}

But that gives this output in Postman:
Please see line 3 which mentions xmlns="http://tempuri.org/
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <HelloWorldResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <HelloWorldResult>
                <HelloWorldResult xmlns="http://mileagecount.live.x-rm.com/uploaderapi">Hi there, foo</HelloWorldResult>
            </HelloWorldResult>
        </HelloWorldResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

I believe this is what's causing the client application to reject the response.

[tag:CoreWCF] is .NET Core port of [tag:wcf] so does this answer to How to get rid of tempuri.org in WCF service created by SharePoint Service Factory answer your question?  See also How to eliminate tempuri.org from your service WSDL.

You could add the DataContract attribute first like this : [DataContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/"]. Also the solutions of these two cases could be tried : How can I specify a namespace for OperationContract when using WCF? and Changing namespace for DataContracts in a WCF service.
